# Has anyone been successful with Antlr v4 generating javascript for Hive

Tags: sql, node.js, parsing, hive, antlr4

My aim is to parse SQL (specifically Hive) statements with javascript, preferably Nodejs.  I started out with node-sql-parser which looked promising.  However I found quite a few cases where the parser did not recognize valid SQL like several nested functions on a column in a select clause, and multiple AND clauses in SQL that had lots of joins, unions, etc.  (I've logged as issue but it will take some time).

I decided to look at Antlr v4.  I followed the getting started steps with Hive SQL grammar. (https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/hplsql/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/hive/hplsql/Hplsql.g4); I generated parsers lexers and listeners using Antlr's generation for JavaSCript - all good so far.  Then I tried a simple test as below:

```
const HplsqlLexer = require('./HplsqlLexer');
const HplsqlParser = require('./HplsqlParser');
const input = "select * from table_a"
var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(input);
var lexer = new HplsqlLexer.HplsqlLexer(chars);
var tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new HplsqlParser.HplsqlParser(tokens);
parser.buildParseTrees = true;
const tree = parser.program();
```

I believe "program()" is the entry point into the parser but I could be wrong.  This gave me "ReferenceError: _input is not defined" at the parser.program() line.  I questioned whether the Hplsql.g4 could be missing something but ruled that out.  Then I looked at the generated code in HplsqlParser.js - I added var _input = "" at the top and reran; then it complained ablut LT is not defined.  Feels like a rabbit hole.

Next steps include running the Java version of the Antlr parser, then Calcite.  (hplsql.org is not what I am looking for).
node --version:  v15.2.1.  Any suggestions or pointers would be helpful.

Comment: That grammar contains target-dependent code. I would assume that it's Java. You will need to change the .g4 file to JavaScript syntax. Delete your added def for _input, and change from "_input" to "this._input", then see where that takes you. For additional changes, look at the types at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/JavaScript/src/antlr4.

Comment: I thought the grammar file was language independent.  And Antlr would generate code in the language target. I have tried a few variations on _input.  When it seems to be accepted, an LT error comes up (I have no idea on how to resolve this one).  Thanks for the link to Antlr's source code for javascript generation.  I certainly didn't think I would have to poke into the source to get this to work.

Comment: Negative. That is one of the great downfalls of Antlr: target-specific code can be embedded in the CFG, and further, there's nothing in the .g4 file that states explicitly that this grammar must be generated for a specific target. For further changes, "getText()" => "text". You'll have to do something for "equalsIgnoreCase", like convert it to lowercase, then compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by kaby76: the grammar contains target specific (Java) code. You need to replace all Java code between `{` and `}?` with TypeScipt code.

For example, this Java code:

```java
{!_input.LT(2).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("TRANSACTION")}?
```

can be rewritten into this:

```
{this._input.LT(2).text.toUpperCase() !== 'TRANSACTION'}?
```

(not tested!)

### EDIT

I quickly did a global search and replace for pattern `_input\.LT\((\d+)\).getText\(\)\.equalsIgnoreCase\("(\w+)"\)` with replacement string `(this._input.LT(\1).text.toUpperCase() === '\2')`, which resulted in the following grammar: https://gist.github.com/bkiers/bb68b25ed03cf6c8ffae2709606d27a5

### EDIT 2

> I am surprised that Antlr even has a flag for -Dlanguage=JavaScript for parser generation. What's the point if it still is essentially Java?

The `-Dlanguage=JavaScript` makes sure to generate the lexer and parser classes in JavaScript. What it does not do, is rewrite [semantic predicates](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md), which are just copied "as-is". Note that it is always recommended to *not* use semantic predicates because of that, but move such target specific code into visitor or listener classes.

Comment: Thanks Bart (and kaby76), I understand now what both of you are saying.  I am surprised that Antlr even has a flag for -Dlanguage=JavaScript for parser generation.  What's the point if it still is essentially Java?

Comment: @MikeLapenna you're welcome. Also checkout my **EDIT 2**